# Log / Structuremap nested container disposing

Tags: structuremap, dispose

How can I get a log showing which instances the nested container of Structuremap is disposing?

Answer (score 1):

Just to help the people who will stumble upon this, here is an answer from the man Jermey himself. He answered the question on his blog [here](http://jeremydmiller.com/2012/01/11/kicking-off-structuremap-3/#comment-49).

**You *could* go run thru the IContainer.Model structure and figure out what has been created as an IDisposable transient during the nested container. Not really something I anticipated here.**